# Loop over null throws error in Production but not Sandbox?

Tags: visualforce, selectoption, extension

I'm trying to debug someone else's code where they're trying to populate a visualforce picklist with options from the controller. Without going into detail, the page is failing to load because the constructor that populates the picklist is attempting to loop over a null list so we get the "Argument 1 cannot be null" message, which is to be expected.

However, I cannot recreate the issue in the sandbox? My debug statements clearly show that the list that is being iterated over is null but the page loads regardless.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
public List<SelectOption> getPublicOptions() {
    List<Custom_Object__c> objs = [Select Id, Name FROM Custom_Object__c Where Id = :customVariable Order By Name];
    system.debug('-------objs List-------'+objs); // This is showing ()
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    Debug log shows fatal error at this line-->for (Custom_Object__c co :objs){
          options.add(new SelectOption(co.id,co.Name));
    }

    return options;
}
```

Comment: A query like you've got into the `List<Custom_Object__c> objs` will never be null. It'll be an empty list - just as you demonstrate with `( )` from the debug. As written, your code would work just fine. `objs` will be an empty list and the `for` loop will simply have no work to do and return the empty `options` collection. What else is happening on the "fatal error" line in your actual code? (The error describes your code sending a null into the first parameter of some method where that is disallowed)

Comment: Agreed with @Mark Pond. The issue may not be in the for 'header' but in the body of the loop itself. Could one of your custom objects have a null name?

Comment: Thanks @MarkPond and mkorman, you're right,  that shouldn't be producing an error since it's an empty list and wouldn't have anything to loop over. It's a strange situation because there were apparently no modifications made to the code and one day it just broke and started throwing the "Argument 1 cannot be null" message in production?

Comment: Could it be that you've simplified your code in the example? The exception is more likely to be thrown on the line below (where you add a new SelectOption to the list). If you've simplified the code for the question, could you post the entire snippet?